# React google maps infoWindow covering the Marker

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to show infoWindow on the above Market but it covers the whole marker,
i have tried setting the pixelOffset and positon but neither of these worked.
how can i achive the expected result.

i know this question is duplicate, but i have tried other stackoverflow question but not able to get any luck.

here is my snippet, help would be appreciated

```
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript, Marker, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const center = {
  lat: 23.043324,
  lng: 72.5460073
};

const libraries = ['places'];
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

const GoogleMaps = ({ containerStyle, latLong, address, placeName, hidePrompt }) => {
  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={apiKey} libraries={libraries}>
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{ width: '400px', height: '400px', ...containerStyle }}
        center={Object.values(latLong).length ? latLong : center}
        zoom={15}
      >
        {Object.values(latLong).length && (
          <>
            <Marker position={latLong}>
              {!hidePrompt && (
                <InfoWindow position={latLong} >
                  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                    <span style={{ fontSize: '12px', fontWeight: '700' }}>{placeName}</span>
                    <span style={{ fontSize: '12px' }}>{address}</span>
                  </div>
                </InfoWindow>
              )}
            </Marker>
          </>
        )}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};

export default GoogleMaps;
```

i checked the docs and get to know about `anchor` prop but i didn't find any example to follow.